# Time conversion to number

Tags: r, regex, string, time, numeric

There is a vector with a time value. How can I remove a colon and convert a text value to a numeric value. i.e. from "10:01:02" - character to 100102 - numeric. All that I could find is presented below.

```
> x <- c("10:01:02", "11:01:02")  
> strsplit(x, split = ":")
[[1]]
[1] "10" "01" "02"

[[2]]
[1] "11" "01" "02"
```

Comment: Have you considered to convert the time into POSIXct using a dummy date.? POSIXct is a number  essentially but works much better with subsequents operations like time differences, or plotting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to replace `:` with `""`. After that, use `as.numeric` to do the conversion.

```
x <- as.numeric(gsub(":", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
```

Or we can use the regex suggest by Soto

```
x <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', x))
```

Comment: or `as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', x))`

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer if you like

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do everything in one line, you can use the `destring()` function from `taRifx` to remove everything that isn't a number and convert the result to numeric.

```
taRifx::destring(x)
```

This will also work if some of your data's formatted in a different way, such as `"10-01-02"`, though you may have to set the value of `keep`.

```
destring("10-10-10", keep = "0-9")
```

And if you don't want to have to install the `taRifx` package you can define the `destring()` function locally.

```
destring <- function(x, keep = "0-9.-") 
{
    return(as.numeric(gsub(paste("[^", keep, "]+", sep = ""), 
        "", x)))
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Brēza thanks for the answer. But for me the simplicity of understanding and realization is important. Your answer is difficult for me

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
x <- as.numeric(x)
```

and then to make sure

```
class(x)
```

Comment: This leads to `NA`.

Comment: > x <- as.numeric(x)  
Warning message:  
NAs introduced by coercion. Unfortunately did not work